# How to Rotate an Equation in CorelDraw?

Tags: corel-draw

Can't seem to get the rotation handles to show up and the Transform doesnt' work on an equation object.  Any ideas?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try this: group the formula together with a transparent rectangle then the rotate handles will appear.

- Click the formula to select it.
- Double-click the rectangle tool to create a rectangle with the dimensions of the formula object.
- Remove the outline and fill of the rectangle.
- Select both objects
- Ctrl+G
  Now you should be able to rotate the group.